# how to link to a image generated by javascript in play?

Tags: javascript, html, scala, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I am trying to convert the twitter bootstrap example into part of my play framework web-app.

In the give twitter-bootstrap example, I have the html contains

```
<img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#6a6a6a/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
```

My goal is convert it to part of my `index.scala.html`.

I tried following:

```
<img data-src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#6a6a6a/text:Second slide")" alt="Second slide">
```

It doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<img data-src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/holder.js")/900x500/auto/#666:#6a6a6a/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
```

You need to pass `routes.Assets.at` the name of the file to discover the route for. The rest of the `data-src` attribute is specific to how the javascript in Bootstrap interprets this field — Play isn't going to understand it.